# JavaScriptCore console.log

Tags: javascript, objective-c, xcode, macos, core-foundation

I've put together a very simple program that uses JavaScriptCore to evaluate JS:

```
#import <CoreFoundation/CoreFoundation.h>
#import <JavaScriptCore/JavaScriptCore.h>

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    JSGlobalContextRef ctx = JSGlobalContextCreate(NULL);

    FILE *f = fopen(argv[1],"r");
    char * buffer = malloc(10000000);
    fread(buffer,1,10000000,f);

    CFStringRef strs = CFStringCreateWithCString(NULL, buffer, kCFStringEncodingASCII);

    JSStringRef jsstr = JSStringCreateWithCFString(strs);
    JSValueRef result = JSEvaluateScript(ctx, jsstr, NULL, NULL, 0, NULL);

    double res  = JSValueToNumber(ctx, result, NULL);
    JSGlobalContextRelease(ctx);

    printf("%lf\n", res);
    return 0;
}
```

The idea here is that the last value is expected to be a `Number`, and that value is printed.  This works for valid javascript code, such as

```
var square = function(x) { return x*x; }; square(4)
```

However, if the code tries to perform a `console.log`, the program segfaults.  Is there a log function available in JSC or do I have to roll my own?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You do have to provide your own console log if using the JavaScriptCore framework from Mac or IOS.

Here is some code that worked for me (sorry it is Objective-C rather than standard C as per your code above):

```
JSContext *javascriptContext  = [[JSContext alloc] init];
javascriptContext[@"consoleLog"] = ^(NSString *message) {
    NSLog(@"Javascript log: %@",message);
};
```

Then you use it from Javascript by:

```
consoleLog("My debug message");
```

Note that I have tried to define a vararg version (log taking multiple parameters) but I couldn't get this to work correctly across the framework api.

Note that this solution uses features introduced with the new Objective-C API for the JavaScriptCore.framework introduced at the same time as IOS 7.  If you are looking for an intro to this well-integrated bridge between Objective-C and Javascript, check out the 2013 WWDC introduction "Integrating JavaScript into Native Apps" session on Apple's developer network: https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2013/?id=615

Update to answer:

For those of you wanting to maximise your javascript code reuse without refactoring, I've managed to get a version working that declares a log of the form *console.log()* :

```
JSContext *javascriptContext  = [[JSContext alloc] init];
[javascriptContext evaluateScript:@"var console = {}"];
javascriptContext[@"console"][@"log"] = ^(NSString *message) {
    NSLog(@"Javascript log: %@",message);
};
```

Then you use it from Javascript by:

```
console.log("My debug message");
```

Comment: I also did a small research on the topic http://kalapun.com/blog/2014/03/26/ios-and-javascript-first-try/

Comment: @TarasKalapun your link 404s.  I think http://kalapun.com/posts/ios-and-javascript-first-try/ is the correct link now

Comment: You probably want to see errors from JavaScriptCore as well.     `javascriptContext.exceptionHandler = ^(JSContext *context, JSValue *exception) {
        NSLog(@"JS Error: %@", exception);
    };`

Comment: This is great for strings. But what if you want to be able to do everything you can do within console.log in regular javascript ? Is a simple solution just to check if the input is within quotes, and if not, then try to eval() ?

Comment: @RahulIyer See my answer - you can use JS string interpolation.

Answer (score 20):

**Swift 3.0**

```
let javascriptContext = JSContext()
javascriptContext?.evaluateScript("var console = { log: function(message) { _consoleLog(message) } }")
let consoleLog: @convention(block) (String) -> Void = { message in
    print("console.log: " + message)
}
javascriptContext?.setObject(unsafeBitCast(consoleLog, to: AnyObject.self), forKeyedSubscript: "_consoleLog" as (NSCopying & NSObjectProtocol)!)
```

**Swift 2.1**

```
let javascriptContext = JSContext()
javascriptContext.evaluateScript("var console = { log: function(message) { _consoleLog(message) } }")
let consoleLog: @convention(block) String -> Void = { message in
    print("console.log: " + message)
}
javascriptContext.setObject(unsafeBitCast(consoleLog, AnyObject.self), forKeyedSubscript: "_consoleLog")
```

Then you use it from Javascript by:

```
console.log("My debug message");
```

Answer (score 5):

```
self.jsContext = JSContext()
self.jsContext.evaluateScript(...)       
let logFunction: @convention(block) (String) -> Void  = { (string: String) in
    print(string)
}

self.jsContext.setObject(logFunction, forKeyedSubscript: "consoleLog" as NSCopying & NSObjectProtocol)
```

Comment: _This_ is why we come to SOF

Answer (score 3):

You can debug JS file attached to context in Safari.

Steps:

1) Start Safari

2) In Safari, enable the Develop menu by going to "Preferences" -> "Advanced" -> "Show Develop menu in menu bar"

3) Go to Develop menu -> "Simulator" or name of your computer -> select "Automatically show web inspector for JSContexts" and "Automatically pause connecting to JSContexts"

4) Re-run your project and Safari should auto-show the web inspector

Answer (score 2):

Swift 5.0

The other suggestions didn't work for me, so I found a [web post](https://christiantietze.de/posts/2020/06/console-log-javascriptcore-swift/) that explains how to do it now.Essentially

```
let logFunction: @convention(block) (String) -> Void = { string in
    print("JS_Console:", string)
}
if let console = context.objectForKeyedSubscript("console") {
    console.setObject(logFunction, forKeyedSubscript: "log") // works for me
    // is this needed? "console.setObject(unsafeBitCast(logFunction, to: AnyObject.self), forKeyedSubscript: "log")
}
```

log.console is variadic, but I could find no way to utilize it even though the link above suggests it's possible. What I [did discover](https://stackoverflow.com/a/610415/1633251) though is that you can use JavaScript interpolation to get values, for example:

```
console.log(`getCombinedFrameYaw: ${frameYaw} rot=${pathRotation}`)
```

Comment: I got it to work using the subscript extensions from that post