# Why doesn't console.log work in the JSC environment but it works in Safari's debug console

Tags: javascript, safari, javascriptcore

When I use the JSC (JavaScriptCore) engine provided in the System Library, it acts differently then when using Safari's debug console

```
$ /System/Library/Frameworks/JavaScriptCore.framework/Versions/A/Resources/jsc
>>> console.log("hello");
Exception: TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'console.log')
```

When `console.log("hello");` works perfectly fine in Safari.

Comment: Because there's no `console` object in JSC, apparently.

Comment: @Barmar can you convert this to an answer so I can accept it? - Thanks

Comment: I don't know anything about JSC, I just based that on the symptom. What's wrong with John Hascall's answer, that explains how to solve it?

Comment: @Barmar the problem has nothing to do with an Objective C or C environment but a JSC environment

Comment: OK, I've reopened the question. You should put your solution in an answer, not the question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**TL;DR**

```
var Console = function () {
    this.log = function(msg){ debug(msg) }; 
};
var console = new Console();
console.log("hello");
```

Safari creates a console object that is available in the debug console, but not in the JSC environment. See Safari's console documentation [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/AppleApplications/Conceptual/Safari_Developer_Guide/Console/Console.html)

Adding my own console object that wraps the JSC debug method solved my problem:

```
$ /System/Library/Frameworks/JavaScriptCore.framework/Versions/A/Resources/jsc
>>> var Console = function () {
...     this.log = function(msg){ debug(msg) };
... };
undefined
>>> var console = new Console();
undefined
>>> console.log("hello");
-> hello
undefined
```

Comment: Does that mean that the debug() does everything that console.log normally does ? That's awesome! Please tell me it is what I think it is!!!

Comment: @KaizerSozay unfortunately, it is not. This is just a hacky way of allowing calls to `console.log`. For it to function like the actual console object you would need to implement everything Webkit ([source](https://github.com/WebKit/webkit/blob/89c28d471fae35f1788a0f857067896a10af8974/Source/JavaScriptCore/runtime/ConsoleObject.cpp)), or V8 ([source](https://github.com/v8/v8/blob/4b9b23521e6fd42373ebbcb20ebe03bf445494f9/src/d8-console.cc)) implements depending on the console object flavor you want. @Sunil is going to be a little more robust, as it handles multiple params

Answer (score 2):

The console object doesn't exist in JSC -- you can add it if you like [JavaScriptCore console.log](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19649932/javascriptcore-console-log/21325240#21325240)

Answer (score 2):

I've ended up with this one liner that works on other JS engines along with JSC compatibility:

```
console = console || { log: (...args) => debug(Array.prototype.slice.call(args).join(' ')) }
```

Answer (score 1):

I learned from the answers above.

Though, as I not see a goal, I presume it was to see output on stdout:

```
print('string')
```

And when ready, use a stream editor to substitute 'print' with 'console.log'.